# Oracle APEX Form-automatic row (DML) display message if the user does not make any changes

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a form page that uses the Form-automatic row (DML) process. I want to display a message that says "Row not updated" if the user does not make any changes to the form on SAVE button.

By defualt the SAVE button simply submits the page without any message if the form has not been changed.

Please advice.

apex19.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is check on the client side if anything changed. This can be achieved by using javascript function [apex.page.isChanged()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.page.html#.isChanged).

One way to implement this is to add a dynamic action to your SAVE button and set an item (P1_CHANGED) to 'Y' when `!apex.page.isChanged()`. Then create a dummy page process with server side condition P1_CHANGED = Y and success messages "Row not Saved"

Comment: Thank you, @Koen. It worked like a charm. Here's the code:

if (apex.page.isChanged()) {
  apex.item('P9_CHANGED').setValue('Y');
} else {
  apex.item('P9_CHANGED').setValue('N');
}